# Running Google AppEngine Python SDK on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run GAE for Python 2.7 on my Raspberry Pi Model B, and I'm following the tutorial exactly, but any time I enter the "dev_appserver.py" command, it comes back:

bash: dev_appserver.py: command not found

or

sudo: dev_appserver.py: command not found

Is it not possible to run this on the Pi?

Comment: I assume you try to run the SDK. ? I do not think it is possible, bacause of the kind of processor the Raspberry uses.

Comment: What do you plan to do with it once it is working? I assume you will need sqllite and run dev server with the host option?

Comment: @peterretief The end goal is to port an existing GAE-Java app to python and submit it to the Pi Store. We'll see how far I get :P

Comment: @Kaceykaso sounds nice, I wrote some stuff for pi awhile back, thought of using appengine but there are many smaller web servers about

Comment: @peterretief yea, got it to run last night, but super slow. Don't think I'll be going that route; at least not hosting the server anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kaceykaso,

You just need to specify the exact path to dev_appserver.py or put it in your PATH first.

For example, here are the steps I did from downloading to running on my raspberry pi:

```
wget http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_1.7.4.zip
unzip google_appengine_1.7.4.zip
cd google_appengine/demos/guestbook
../../dev_appserver.py .
```

This worked for me with no errors.
To avoid typing the exact path to dev_appserver.py each time, you can add it to your PATH by entering this in the shell: 
(this path assumes your username is "pi" and you unzipped appengine in your home directory, otherwise you'll need to change this path slightly)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/google_appengine
```

This allows the method you tried to work:

```
dev_appserver.py .
```

To have this added to your PATH automatically everytime you login, you can paste that PATH line at the end of your .bashrc file, which is at /home/pi/.bashrc

Comment: I hadn't specified the entire path because I had navigated to the directory and then called the command. But I will try this when I get home tonight.

Comment: I got it to run last night by running: "sudo python ../../dev_appserver.py ." Still super slow tho, don't think I'll be developing on the Pi, just testing. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Yep, I noticed the Pi is a little slow for some things, too.  I'm still figuring out which ideas work best on it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any experience with the Raspberry Pi, but you could try prefixing it with `python` to indicate you want to execute the file with Python (your error means it is trying to execute the `dev_appserver.py` command, which it doesn't recognize):

```
python /path/to/dev_appserver.py /path/to/your/app
```

You could also adjust your paths to include `/path/to/google_appengine/` so that that location was searched and the command was found, but again I'm not familiar with Raspberry Pi so that may not be an option :)

It appears (at least anecdotally) that [someone](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/oAFns0vAaXE/14lnjwk1RQEJ) got it running, but I imagine the performance would be lacking a bit.

Comment: This would be my guess too - dev_appserver.py probably is not in the path.

Comment: @rbanffy Yeah, of the two I'd say that's the better option :)

Comment: I saw this, but it was more one guy theorizing, and no real implementation. Also, I think they might be on to something in regards to the power of the Pi's cpu :-/

Answer (score 0):

@Eric Olson's path no longer works but his answer is a great one. It seems the wget link below does work at least now (change the release to the most current). Also, the other commands that make this super easy, the unzip and remove commands) are included for ease of reference:

```
wget -O gae.zip https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.15.zip
unzip gae.zip
rm gae.zip
```